# open webview inside a linked list view in android

Tags: android

In my android application i would like to use linked list view wherein i would like to open a webview on click of initial list view.
Is it possible to open a webview inside a listview in android??

Please share your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Webview w = (Webview) findwiewbyid...
w.loadUrl(''http://yourlink.com'')
but you need to create a method to retrieve the link in your listview
parent.getItemAtPosition(position) something like this.